# In merging database records, how much paper trail should I leave?

Tags: database

A lot of duplication has crept into a client's database through poor initial design.  I am writing some stored procedures to merge users etc.  It would be nice to accomplish the merge and still be able to do an undo or a rollback without doing a full database restore.

My original question was how much other housekeeping or record keeping do I need to do, and how do I do it?  I think I've addressed that.  The question now is whether there is anything beyond the following that needs to be done.  I realize now this was a poor type of question for this site.  In compensation for that, I'll offer to share my experience with anybody who also needs to build a duplicate record merging tool.

The basic pseudocode for a merge is:

1. Let from_id = the record to merge (the mergee). Let into_id = the record that all the from_id references need to point to after the merge.
2. Check the database schema against known parameters and return a schema_changed error if changed.
3. Use information in merge_config and merge_referrer_config tables to add an entry to merge_log and merge_referrer_log tables to give detailed instructions for every piece of data that needs to be changed to accomplish the merge.  This log becomes the instructions for a rollback (undo).  The config tables give complete information about everywhere the merging records are referenced in the database.
4. Follow the instructions just added to the merge log tables to update all pertinent (as defined in merge_config and merge_referrer_config tables) tables to set pertinent columns = into_id where pertinent column = from_id.
5. Mark the merged_to column of the record for from_id with the into_id.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: This actually is probably a poor question, for which I apologize.  I am editing it with my new, improved logic, which doesn't really improve the question, but may help somebody.  I have the SQL code for this if anybody is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should do a back up anyway, in case something goes horribly wrong.

In terms of an audit trail, I'd be tempted by a duplicates table, with an extra column for when it got 'merged' out then house keep that. Say chuck any thing more than  X old from duplicates before a merge run. Another option I've seen, is a weighting put on how different the records are. "Exact duplicate" is 0 everything different but the key is a 100. Then  chuck / keep based on the weighting.

Whatever approach you take, look at it on the basis of you audit every sniff at the start and then as "you" get a feel for the data, you can silently bin it, or look at prioritising for critical weaknesses in the system